# Vim custom colorscheme problems

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I’ve been trying to get vim to highlight arithmetic operators (+,-,*,=, etc.) for hours and hours. If I type

```
:syntax keyword op TEST
:highlight link op Operator
:highlight Operator ctermfg=9
```

Into vim in command mode, it highlights “TEST” just like the other operators. If I put the exact same thing in my colorscheme script, it only highlights the operators defined in the syntax file (In, not, and, etc. in the case of python). I either need to know what’s going wrong or a different way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax elements are local to buffer. Therefore, you can't write them into colorscheme file. You're supposed to write syntax file instead.

Note that if you're still missing basics, such as autocommands, filetypes, local-to-buffer things, and such, you should step back and learn something on that matter first.

Comment: Okay, good to know, thanks. Is there a way to avoid having to write a syntax file for each language I’m writing, At least for stuff like arithmetic operators which every language has? Also do you have any advice on the best way to learn basics like autocommands, filetypes, etc.?

Comment: @JohnWalthall 1) Well, yes, but that could be tricky. 2) There's no single thing every language has. Anyway, re-defining global highlight group, such as Operator is the way to go. 3) `:help` is your best friend.